# The compiler extension in package 'ballerina:graphql:1.8.0' failed to complete. null

Tags: ballerina

I am getting an error when compiling my Ballerina code in version 2201.5.0. Any idea what is happening?

Error:
`error: compilation failed: The compiler extension in package 'ballerina:graphql:1.8.0' failed to complete. null`

Comment: Could you kindly share the reproducible code, @AvishkaAriyaratne? I'm curious if the issue you mentioned is occurring for any code you write or if it's specific to a certain code snippet.

Comment: @MOHAMEDSABTHAR I have shared this with another person in the team. Let me share with you as well

Answer (score 2):

Ballerina GraphQL services do not allow the return of Ballerina tuple types. However, in the code where the mentioned error occurred, a [time:Utc](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/time/2.2.5#Utc) type from the Ballerina Time module was used as a return type, which is a tuple. Therefore it should return a compilation error. Due to an existing issue with the GraphQL compiler plugin that prevents returning this error. The issue will be fixed with the GraphQL next patch version.